# Group by in sql for two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have this table

```
SELECT 
      [WeldStatus]
      ,PackageId

  FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[JointHistory]
```

[image]

How can I group by this query to calculate `total testpackage` and `total accept` and `total remain`?

For example for packageid=6030 I need this:

```
packageid   total   accept remain 
6030        4       3      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` and `Group By`

```
SELECT 
      PackageId,
      count(*) as total,
      sum(case [WeldStatus] when 'Accept' then 1 end) as accept,
      sum(case [WeldStatus] when 'accept' then 0 else 1 end) as remain
  FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[JointHistory]
group by PackageId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
packageid
,count(*) as 'total'
,sum(case when weldstatus = 'Accept' then 1 else 0 end) as 'accept'
,sum(case when weldstatus is null then 1 else 0 end) as 'remain'
FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[JointHistory]
group by packageid
```

"sum(case when..." has saved me so many times. NULLs can be a pain but the case when saves you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expression with in your aggregation to achieve your desired output.

```
SELECT
    PackageId,
    SUM (CASE WHEN WeldStatus = 'Accept' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AcceptCount, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN WeldStatus IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RemainCount, 
    COUNT (*) AS Total
FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[JointHistory]
GROUP BY PackageId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select packageid, SUM(TOTAL),  SUM(ACCEPT),  SUM(REMAIN) from (
select packageid, 1 as TOTAL, 
case 
when WeldStatus='Accept' then 1 else 0
END as ACCEPT,
case 
when WeldStatus  IS NULL then 1 else 0
END as REMAIN
from JointHistory
) group by packageid
```

Comment: `WeldStatus='Remain'` is not in the sample data, just null

Answer (score 1):

If `WeldStatus` only takes on the values of `'Accept'` or `NULL`, then a simple method is:

```
SELECT PackageId, count(*) as total,
       count(WeldStatus) as accept,
       count(*) - count(WeldStatus) as remain
FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[JointHistory] jh
GROUP BY PackageId;
```

I'm the first to admit that this relies on the assumption of having a single value or `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT PackageId,
      COUNT(*) AS total,
      SUM(CASE WHEN [WeldStatus] = 'Accept' THEN 1 END) AS accept,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL([WeldStatus],'') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS remain
  FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[JointHistory]
group by PackageId;